# Sourcetree - is there an equivalent of tortoise's Repo browser

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm investigating the features of sourcetree and it looks like it has everything I need, however I am looking for an equivalent of TortoiseSVN's Repo Browser.

This allows me to view a directory and see the date author, and commit id and for every file. This can be really handy so I was wondering how I can get the same view in SourceTree. I can use the "All Files" option on the File status tab to see all files, but this isn't quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think [tortoise git](https://tortoisegit.org/) is **exactly** what you're looking for. There is a built in [repo browser](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-repobrowser.html) with it.

Comment: The screenshot in your link only shows folder structure, but no source control metadata (such as commit id for each file). Ideally I was looking for a way to replicate this view in sourcetree.

Comment: If you right click a file and select "show-log" it will bring up information such as the commit id, author, date, actions, see [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html) . I suggest you download it and have a play. If its not what you're looking for apologies.

Comment: not quite, I can do that in source tree, I was wondering if I could use source tree to see that information for every file in the folder all at once. Looks like it probably doesnt!

Comment: ah no, thats not possible in SourceTree. Something like GitLab would show you the [file browser](https://about.gitlab.com/features/) history .

Comment: I suspected that was the case. Thanks